# Oracle .NET Provider Not Found on Production Server

Tags: .net, oracle, client, odp.net

In Visual Studio running on an XP 64 bit everything runs fine. I have the web.config with an entry:

( to look for the 'bin' folder of the project where two .DLLs are (Oracle.DataAccess.dll, System.Data.OracleClient.dll)

But, in the Production environment (Windows 2003, 32 bit), I get an error that: 'Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.'
Previously, the error was something like 'Not compatible Provider' because I had an entry in Web.config to include the appropriate DLLs. But I removed those references from Web.Config because, I thought, there could be a conflict between 32 vs 64 bit version. Note, I do have the Oracle Instant Client installed via the GUI application from Oracle.

What kind of .DLLs I can simply copy into the 'bin' folder to make them work on both my Visual Studio in 64 bit as well as in the 32 bit Production server?
Thanks!

Comment: Some progress: After granting 'Network Service' access to the 'bin' folder where the two DLLs are at least, it seems, Oracle.DataAccess.Client part of the programming is working. However, in another page, I am using 'using Oracle.DataAccess.Client' reference in code behind and I get an error: The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client
?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Here is how I solved it:
Removed the .DLLs from the bin file and put back the references in the Web.Config file. After that, on the 32 bit Window 2003 system, simply installed the ODAC1110720 (32 bit) from the Oracle site on the Windows 2003, 32 bit system and all is working just fine!
I hope this will help someone.